how to update PositionHierarchy in dynamics?
How  do you  update a HierarchyPosition entity?
When attempting to PATCH PositionHierarchies I'm getting this error:

{
"Message":"No HT TP resource was found that matches the request URI
'https://xxxxx.operations.dynamics.com/data/PositionHierarchies(PositionId='xxx',HierarchyTypeName='xxx',ValidFrom=2018-09-26T05:00:00Z,ValidTo=2154-11-31T00:00:00Z)'. No route data was found for this request." }

Here's how the entity is defined:

I've also attempted to update this entity with C# using the etag:
        string entityId = retrievedEntity["@odata.etag"]?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityId))
        {
            _logger.LogError("Retrieved entity does not have a valid identifier.");
            return (false, "Retrieved entity does not have a valid identifier.");
        }

        _logger.LogInformation($"Attempting to update PositionHierarchy with ID: {entityId}.");

        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedEntityData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var patchResponse = await _httpClient.PatchAsync($"/data/PositionHierarchies({entityId})", content);
        var patchResponseBody = await patchResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

But getting this error

Unable to update PositionHierarchy with ID: W/"xxxxxxxxxxx=":
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
'https://xxxxxx.operations.dynamics.com/data/PositionHierarchies(W/"xxxxxxxxxxx=")'.
No route data was found for this request."}

How do you update a HierarchyPosition entity?
